# State pattern in JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, state-pattern

I need to implement a state pattern in JPA.
I'm working with a delivery System for products. I can create orders, each order contains an order status **(for example: Sent, Delivered, Cancelled, etc)**, so the order will be in different states.

Here's my code *(I ommited details for the sake of simplicity)*

Order.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name="Orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Embedded
    private OrderStatus status;
    ....
}
```

OrderStatus.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Embeddable
public abstract class OrderStatus {
    private String name;

    private Date startDate;

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn( name="id_order" )
    private Order order;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public boolean canAddItem() { return false; }

    public boolean canAssign() { return false; }

    public boolean canRefuse() { return false; }

    public boolean canDeliver() { return false; }

    public boolean canFinish() { return false; }

    public boolean canCancel() { return false; }

    public boolean addItem() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("No se puede realizarse esta accion");
    }

    public boolean assign(DeliveryMan deliveryMan) throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("No se puede realizarse esta accion");
    }

    public boolean refuse() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("No se puede realizarse esta accion");
    }

    public boolean deliver() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("No se puede realizarse esta accion");
    }

    public boolean cancel() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("No se puede realizarse esta accion");
    }

    public boolean finish() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("No se puede realizarse esta accion");
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

Pending.java

```
   @Embeddable
   public class Pending extends OrderStatus{

    public Pending() {
    }

    public Pending(Order order, Date startDate) {
        this.setStartDate(startDate);
        this.setOrder(order);
        this.setName("Pending");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean assign(DeliveryMan deliveryMan) throws Exception{
       Order order = this.getOrder();
       order.setDeliveryMan(deliveryMan);
       Assigned assigned = new Assigned(order, order.getDateOfOrder());
       order.setStatus(assigned);
       return true;
    }
}
```

If I do something like the following

CreateOrder.java

```
Order order_1 = new Order();
order_1.setStatus(new Pending(order_1, order_1.getDateOfOrder()));
orderRepository.save(order_1);
```

Then in the next code snippet I'm trying to move from **Pending** state to **Assigned** state.

TestState.java

```
private void TestState() throws Exception {
     Optional<Order> order = orderRepository.findById(1L);
     if(order.isPresent()) {
         // Get the order status which was previously setted
         OrderStatus orderStatus = order.get().getStatus();
         // invoke assign method 
         orderStatus.assign(new DeliveryMan());
     }
}
```

If OrderStatus is abstract I get this exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : com.bd.tpfinal.model.OrderStatus
```

If OrderStatus is **not** an abstract class, I get this output

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No se puede realizarse esta accion
```

This is triggering the method hosted in the superclass.

My Order table seems fine. It contains extra fields (name = Pending, startdate = Date.now()). But I cannot trigger the methods for each state.

I've read that inheritance is not supported using embedded types in JPA / hibernate.
Any help? thanks

Comment: If a class is abstract it can not be instantiated. To instantiate an object from a class it should be a normal class. But when you call assign method it is throwing new Exception. I think that is causing your error. You must do your business logic there

Comment: I know, I'm not instantiating the abstract class. There's a hierarchy there. I'm instantiating concrete classes Pending and Assigned, inheriting from the abstract class. The problem is in  the embedded type and the hierarchy.

Comment: Ooh I understand. I remember JPA always needs empty constructor so I think JPA is somehow instantiating the object behind in my opinion though I did not read any documentation. So here it may be the same thing. Maybe behind the scene JPA is trying to instantiate that OrderStatus. Because when you delete abstract it is also throwing that exception which means that object is instantiated from OrderStatus not Pending or Assigned classes

Comment: Please look at here maybe it will help you https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-entity-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/